# how to play gfwl games without needing live?

Tags: windows-7, games-for-windows-live

I want to play some games that are GFWL enabled,but have no desire to log in or play multiplayer on those games(the games in question I know for a fact have a client-based singleplayer mode so nothing needs to be downloaded to run those)
the way it's set up makes it a big hassles as I have to install a lot of M.S. bloatware before the game even becomes playable,and then it wants me to sign in and share every detail about it. 
is there any way to reduce the amount of GFWL applications needed to run a game, or do I need to buy different games?

Comment: I believe GFWL is being phased out by Microsoft at some point in the near future, so if you're patient you should be able to play those games without it.

Comment: what about older games that already come bundled with it and depend on GFWL to even launch? will those games become unplayble once it's phased out?

Comment: My vague recollection is that there will be a few GFWL servers up to deploy patches for those games so that they don't require GFWL anymore. Once those are taken down you'll have to hope the company that made the game posts a fix on their website.

Comment: @ZCoder What games are you referring to?

Answer (score -1):

Some publishers removed the "Games for Windows Live" from their games other didn't. You can verify this on the publisher- or the game-website.
So if you want to play a game with GFWL you need to install the client software. Some DLCs for those games are only available through the GFWL-Marketplace.

You can download the newest client here:
http://www.xbox.com/en-US/live/pc/DownloadClient

Please read the FAQ about the discontinuation of the marketplace:
http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-on-other-devices/windows/pc-marketplace-closing